# UITableViewController, MVC,

Tags: ios

Is the `UITablviewController` part of the controller layer or the View class in the classic MVC Pattern? I am confused about it and I like to organize my code into groups to conform to the MVC pattern myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Like the name suggests `UITableViewController` is the Controller. `UITableView` is the View.

You can create your view in a xib file or by code inside your view controller. (`loadView` and `viewDidLoad`)Your view controller can extend the `UITableViewController`, providing the view it with data through `UITableViewDataSource` and handling its events/actions through `UITableViewDelegate`.

Put all your data and business logic in another class which will act as your Model.

Graphic was found in Standford iOS Lecture Series on [iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-hd/id395605774).